# What is the proper way of organizing http services in an angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, angular-services

When I want to get data from backend, I use http client in a service separate from my component. So to get data (e.g. list of actors) in a component I inject my "factory" and subscribe to observables returned by it. It works fine.

```js
@Injectable()
export class Factory{

    constructor(private httpClient : HttpClient){}

    getActors(): Observable<Actor[]>{
        return this.httpClient.get<Actor[]>('api/actor');
    }
}
```

But then when I need other data (e.g. list of movies) in the same component where I need an actors list, I just declare another method in that same factory service. The data returned from different methods of the same service may or may not be related to each other in the db. It is just easier for me to put everything in one service to use in a big separate part of the project (a module).

```js
@Injectable()
export class Factory{

    constructor(private httpClient : HttpClient){}

    getActors(): Observable<Actor[]>{
        return this.httpClient.get<Actor[]>('api/actor');
    }

    getMovies(): Observable<Movie[]>{
        return this.httpClient.get<Movie[]>('api/movie');
    }
}
```

Now, often I need to receive the same data (a list of movies) in a different part of the project (different module). So I create a new factory service in this other part. And in it I declare a method that does the same as a method in the first service.

I feel like that is not preferable. If for example the API changes I will have to change it in two different parts of the project. It goes against the DRY principle.

Another way I see is to create separate services for every entity I have in a project. But then I'll have to inject as many services in the constructor of my component as many there are entities needed for it.

What is the proper way to organize your http services in an angular app?

Comment: You can use the **same service** in differents components (so you needn't repeat methods or services). And there're no "rule". Personal opinion: If a service is a CRUD should be separate, one table in dbs--> one service, but if the services only get a list you can use an unique service for all the "lists". Yes, in a component you probably inject two services, a "dataService" and a "anotherService"

Comment: APIs are CRUD. And there are much more of them than two like in my example above. Is there a way to have a service for each API and then a combined "service of services" to inject just this one service into the component? Is it done like that?

Comment: you can inject so many services you need in a component or, as you say, in a service that return the necessary observables using the methods of this injected services

Comment: @Eliseo Thanks for your input. I understand that I can. But should I? I am chasing after the best practices here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a good question and often times overlooked which may come back as a headache when your app is starting to scale. This question will receive answers that are going be heavily heavily opinionated so take my advice with a pinch of salt.

It's a fine line when you should break into services and depending on what logic it does and to what extent. It will come with experience and working with other projects.

I think it's a good idea to concat most if not all http calls to a single file, because like you said, many components (through services) will most likely share those http calls. There you can also configure environment variables to what url's to use. I leave `GeneralRequestService` as the last layer. Then all services can access it. Otherwise Circular Dependency Injection errors are quick to come.

Comment: Seems at the same time as a good idea and a bad idea to combine them all into a single service, haha. I have components of about 1000 lines and they are painful to debug and update. I understand that methods in this giant service will be separated in 4 alike categories, but still. Can't believe there's no better way